# Why is $\arctan(\tan(y))=y+2k \pi$?

Tags: trigonometry

Why is $\arctan(\tan(y))=y+2k \pi$?

When the cycle of both $\arctan$ and $\tan$ are $\pi$?

Comment: The real answer to this question depends on the domain of $y$ and precise definitions used for arctan, "=" and $y+2k\pi$. Note that arctan is **not** periodic.

Answer (score 3):

It's actually wrong. The correct answer is actually
$$\arctan(\tan(y))=y+k\pi\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}\text{ s.t. } |y+k\pi|<\pi/2$$

if the standard $\arctan:\mathbb{R}\to(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ function is used as an inverse.

Answer (score -2):

because the function tan(x) have period $2\pi$.
I edited the answer.

Comment: Can you expand this a bit? It seems that there's repetition on $[0, 2 \pi)$: https://www.varsitytutors.com/assets/vt-hotmath-legacy/hotmath_help/topics/tangent-of-an-angle/tan2.gif. So I don't see how this means that $x + 2k \pi$ is "unique". It does have a cycle of $2 \pi$. Maybe there's some idea of "enlargening" the cycle $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. However, the output of those two intervals is not the same.

Comment: I made a mistake. If you think the function tangent like $tan(x)=sin(x)/cos(x)$ a tangent function only is not defined when $cos(x)=0$ i.e. when $x=k\pi/2$ or $x=-k\pi/2$ and is clear that have period $2\pi$.

Comment: The period between $k\pi/2$ and $-k \pi/2$ is $\pi$, no?

Comment: you can restrict the domain in each type interval $(-k\pi/2,k\pi/2)$ and the function tangent is bijective in that domain. Then you have a inverse function arctan for each restriction of the tangent function.

Comment: informally $arctan(x)=y$ iff $tan(y)=x$ but $tan(y)=tan(y+2k\pi)$ then if so if you do not specify which tangent domain you restrict yourself to, you have all those possible answers for arctan.

Comment: I don't get it, what you mean by "inverse function arctan for each restriction ..."?

Comment: So it doesn't matter, whether there are "two points having the same value" in $2 \pi$ cycle? E.g. $\pi/2$, $3 \pi / 2$.